# Programmatically uninstall a Steam app

Tags: windows, automation, uninstall, steam

I can use the following [SteamCMD](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD) to list the games installed in my local Steam library:

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam> .\steamcmd.exe +login XXXX XXXX +apps_installed +quit
Redirecting stderr to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\logs\stderr.txt'
[  0%] Checking for available updates...
[----] Verifying installation...
Steam Console Client (c) Valve Corporation - version 1653101151
-- type 'quit' to exit --
Loading Steam API...OK
Logging in user 'XXXX' to Steam Public...OK
Waiting for client config...OK
Waiting for user info...OK
1 apps installed :
AppID 588430 : "Fallout Shelter" : C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Fallout Shelter
```

I'd like to programmatically uninstall this app, however the following command doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam> .\steamcmd.exe +login XXXX XXXX +app_uninstall 588430 +quit
Redirecting stderr to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\logs\stderr.txt'
[  0%] Checking for available updates...
[----] Verifying installation...
Steam Console Client (c) Valve Corporation - version 1653101151
-- type 'quit' to exit --
Loading Steam API...OK
Logging in user 'XXXX' to Steam Public...OK
Waiting for client config...OK
Waiting for user info...OK
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam>
```

The app is still present after executing this. Am I using this command incorrectly, or there another way to programmatically remove Steam apps from the local Steam library?

Comment: Looks like very much not the intended use. Tried the `-complete` parameter yet?

Comment: @DanielB Sure did, no luck unfortunately.. +app_uninstall 588430-complete +quit